# oozie, pass coordinator scheduler time to java action

Tags: java, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I need to pass scheduler time to oozie java action.

For example, I set 1 mınute scheduler time. The current time is 15:45 but any delay or error occurs so the current executed java action time is 15:40 (5 mins delay) and I need to log the execution time in my java action so I need to pass 15.40 value to my java code (jar) as an argument.

How can I achive this?

Thanks

Comment: Search for examples of how to format `coord:nominalTime()` and pass it from Coordinator to Workflow to Action. It's precise to the minute only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the oozie built in [EL function](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.2.0-incubating/WorkflowFunctionalSpec.html#a4.2.2_Basic_EL_Functions) "String timestamp()" to get the time stamp and pass to the java code as an argument.
e.g

```
 <action name='actionJava'>
        <java>
            <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
            <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
            <name>JavaAction</name> 
            <main-class>com.oozie.JTestMain</main-class> 
            <arg>${timestamp()}</arg>
        </java>
       <ok to="end" />
       <error to="killJob" />
 </action>
```